# Bitnami AH02042: rejecting client initiated renegotiation

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, ssl, bitnami

Have a site on AWS Bitnami, received the following error in log last night:

```
 [Tue Feb 21 11:44:24.550083 2017] [ssl:error] [pid 20151:tid 140224130492160] [client 208.93.152.93:41010] AH02042: rejecting client initiated renegotiation
```

Then get the following errors when trying to visit the site.

```
 [Wed Feb 22 14:00:00.739407 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 19875:tid 140224892598080] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
 [Wed Feb 22 14:00:04.737461 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 31984:tid 140233098594112] AH01909: localhost:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
 [Wed Feb 22 14:00:04.894490 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 31985:tid 140233098594112] AH01909: localhost:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
 [Wed Feb 22 14:00:05.036172 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 31985:tid 140233098594112] AH00489: Apache/2.4.23 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2h configured -- resuming normal operations
 [Wed Feb 22 14:00:05.036313 2017] [core:notice] [pid 31985:tid 140233098594112] AH00094: Command line: '/opt/bitnami/apache2/bin/httpd.bin -f /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/httpd.conf'
```

When visiting the site only receive this message 'Your application is not currently available'

Have not made any edits to the site since 1/5/17 no previous errors in the log on the site. Attempted restart, checked paths of SSL logs.

Comment: Did you fix this error? I get this using the Google Auth on callback

Answer (score 1):

The warn messages you are obtaining:

```
[Wed Feb 22 14:00:04.737461 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 31984:tid 140233098594112] AH01909: localhost:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Feb 22 14:00:04.894490 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 31985:tid 140233098594112] AH01909: localhost:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
```

You don't have to worry about them. It is related with the dummy certificate that Bitnami includes in its cloud images. You can find the whole information at https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/components/apache/#how-to-enable-https-support-with-ssl-certificates

I recommend you to take a deeper log to the Apache Log Files. You can share with us the log files:

- /opt/bitnami/apache2/logs/error_log
- /opt/bitnami/apache2/logs/access_log

There should be something there we are missing.